# Does sample() always return float4 in RGBA format in Metal Shading Language?

Tags: metal

I have an MTLTexture in RGBA8Unorm format, and a screen texture (in MTKView) in BGRA8Unorm format (reversed). In the Metal shader, when I sample from that texture using sample(), I get float4. When I write to texture in metal shader, I also write float4. It seems that when I am inside the shader code, float4 always represents the same order of components RGBA regardless of the original format the texture is in ([0] for red, [1] for green, [2] for blue, and [3] for alpha). Is my conclusion correct that the meaning of the components of the sampled/written float4 is always the same **inside the shader**, regardless of what the storage format of the texture is?

UPDATE: I use the following code to write to a texture with RGBA8Unnorm format:

```
kernel void
computeColourMap(constant Uniforms &uniforms [[buffer(0)]],
                 constant array<float, 120> &amps [[buffer(1)]],
                 constant array<float, 120> &red [[buffer(2)]],
                 constant array<float, 120> &green [[buffer(3)]],
                 constant array<float, 120> &blue [[buffer(4)]],
                 texture2d<float, access::write> output [[texture(0)]],
                 uint2 id [[thread_position_in_grid]])
{
    if (id.x >= output.get_width() || id.y >= output.get_height()) {
        return;
    }

    uint i = id.x % 120;

    float4 col (0, 0, 0, 1);
    col.x += amps[i] * red[i];
    col.y += amps[i] * green[i];
    col.z += amps[i] * blue[i];

    output.write(col, id);
}
```

I then use the following shaders for the rendering stage:

```
vertex VertexOut
vertexShader(const device VertexIn *vertexArray [[buffer(0)]],
             unsigned int vid [[vertex_id]])
{
    VertexIn vertex_in = vertexArray[vid];

    VertexOut vertex_out;
    vertex_out.position = vertex_in.position;
    vertex_out.textureCoord = vertex_in.textureCoord;

    return vertex_out;
}

fragment float4
fragmentShader(VertexOut interpolated [[stage_in]],
               texture2d<float> colorTexture [[ texture(0) ]])
{
    const float4 colorSample = colorTexture.sample(nearestSampler,
                                                   interpolated.textureCoord);

    return colorSample;
}
```

where `colourTexture` passed into the fragment shader is the one I generated in RGBA8Unorm format, and in Swift I have:

```
let renderPipelineDescriptor = MTLRenderPipelineDescriptor()
renderPipelineDescriptor.vertexFunction = library.makeFunction(name: "vertexShader")!
renderPipelineDescriptor.fragmentFunction = library.makeFunction(name: "fragmentShader")!
renderPipelineDescriptor.colorAttachments[0].pixelFormat = colorPixelFormat
```

the `colorPixelFormat` of the MTKView is BGRA8Unorm (reversed relative to texture), which is not the same as my texture, but the colours on the screen come out correct.

UPDATE 2: one further pointer that **within a shader** the colour represented by float4 always has order of rgba is: float4 type actually has accessors called v.r, v.g, v.b, v.rgb, etc...

Comment: can you post the shader code?

Comment: @NikosM. - done

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The vector always has 4 components, but the type of the components is not necessarily `float`. When you declare a texture, you specify the component type as a template argument (`texture2d<float ...>` in your code).

For example, from Metal Shading Language Specification v2.1, section 5.10.1:

> The following member functions can be used to sample from a 1D
>   texture.
>
> ```
> Tv sample(sampler s, float coord) const
> ```
>
> Tv is a 4-component vector type based on the templated type  used
>   to declare the texture type. If T is float, Tv is float4. If T is half,
>   Tv is half4. If T is int, Tv is int4. If T is uint, Tv is uint4. If T
>   is short, Tv is short4 and if T is ushort, Tv is ushort4.

The same Tv type is used in the declaration of `write()`. The functions for other texture types are documented in a similar manner.

And, yes, component `.r` always contains the red component (if present), etc. And `[0]` always corresponds to `.r` (or `.x`).

Comment: The question was mainly about the ordering of components in the shader, not whether I can use half for sampling ;) So I guess only the last paragraph is relevant to the question. I will accept, thanks.